# Image of line under linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose that $$ (x,y) \mapsto(\text{transformation}) \mapsto (s,t)  $$ is the linear operator on $\mathbb R^2$ defined by the equations:

> $$2x+y=s \\
> 6x+2y=t \\
> \textrm{Find the image of the line } x+y=1 \textrm{under this operator}$$

I know the standard matrix of $T$ is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
6 & 2 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
And that the transformation can be written as:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
6 & 2 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
u\\
1-u 
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
s \\
t
\end{bmatrix}$$

Why does one simply not multiply the parameterised line with the transformation matrix? Does not multiplying it by the inverse imply that it's a transformation from $s$ to $x$?

[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NM0md.png)

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely right, we can also proceed directly by

$$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
6 & 2 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
u\\
1-u 
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
s \\
t
\end{bmatrix} \implies s=u+1, \: t=4u +2 \implies 2s-\frac12 t=1$$

to obtain the same solution wich is in any case equivalent to solve

$$\begin{bmatrix}
u\\
1-u 
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
6 & 2 
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
s \\
t
\end{bmatrix}$$

which is the way presented in the solution sheet.

Comment: Thank you! I see you parameterised the line x=u, y=1-u. I see how you get s and t from that. But how did you get 2s-1/2t=1.

Comment: @mathswa We see easily that $$4\cdot s=4u+4=(4u+2)+2=t-2$$

Comment: Thank you again. But I don't understand it still. We get s=u+1, t=4u+2. Now we want to write it in terms of x+y=1. We know that x=u, and y=1-u. I tried substituting, but the result is something nonsensical.

Comment: @mathswa As you noticed, we know that $x+y=1$ then we parametrize the line by $(x,y)=(u,1-u)$ then from $[s,t]=T[x,y]=T[u,1-u]$ we obtain $s=u+1$ and $t=4u+2$.